# ¿Cómo hacer un fill en un geom_bar con cuatro variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estoy teniendo problemas para hacer un gráfico de barras bastante sencillo.
Tengo un datos sobre un ranking de calidad del proceso judicial y estoy trabajando sobre tres grupos de países en comparación con Paraguay. Hasta ahí lo puedo realizar sin dificultades.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, este ranking esta compuesto por otras cuatro variables sobre las que también tengo los valores. Digamos que para el caso de Paraguay la tabla sería la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La idea sería poder particionar cada barra de cada año y para cada país en función de estos valores, ya que el ranking no es más que la suma de las mismos.

Intenté hacer un gather para nuclear las cuatro variables con el fin de tener los cuatro valores en una sola variable. Pero de este modo cuando hago el gráfico de barras utilizando esta variable como fill, en lugar del ranking tomar el valor real se grafica con este valor multiplicado por cuatro (justamente porque el gather me repite este valor). Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
datapry_qjp <- usaid_pry2 %>% filter(country == "Paraguay") %>% 
  select(country, year, `Quality of judicial processes index (0-18) (DB17-20 methodology)`,
         `Court structure and proceedings (0-5) (DB17-20 methodology)`, 
         `Case management (0-6) (DB17-20 methodology)`, `Court automation (0-4) (DB17-20 methodology)`,
         `Alternative dispute resolution (0-3) (DB17-20 methodology)`) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(`Quality of judicial processes index (0-18) (DB17-20 methodology)`)) %>% 
  gather(., 4:7, key = componentes, value = valor)
```

Se puede ver como resulta el df:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Siguiendo con el ejemplo de Paraguay, que idealmente me gustaría poder replicar para los tres grupos de comparación, la idea sería tener un gráfico de este estilo (claro que cada espacio con el color de la variable que representa y la leyenda identificando estas cuatro):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Espero haber sido clara y si alguien sabe como ayudarme lo agradecería!!
Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En caso de que a alguien le sea útil lo resolví con el siguiente código:

```
datapry_qjp <- usaid_pry2 %>% filter(country == "Paraguay") %>% 
  select(country, year, `Court structure and proceedings (0-5) (DB17-20 methodology)`, 
         `Case management (0-6) (DB17-20 methodology)`,
         `Court automation (0-4) (DB17-20 methodology)`,
         `Alternative dispute resolution (0-3) (DB17-20 methodology)`) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(`Court structure and proceedings (0-5) (DB17-20 methodology)`)) %>% 
  gather(., 3:6, key = componentes, value = valor)

dataocde_qjp <- usaid_pry2 %>% filter(ocde == 1) %>% 
  select(country, year, `Court structure and proceedings (0-5) (DB17-20 methodology)`, 
         `Case management (0-6) (DB17-20 methodology)`,
         `Court automation (0-4) (DB17-20 methodology)`,
         `Alternative dispute resolution (0-3) (DB17-20 methodology)`, ocde) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(`Court structure and proceedings (0-5) (DB17-20 methodology)`)) %>% 
  gather(., 3:6, key = componentes, value = valor) %>% group_by(year, componentes, ocde) %>% 
  summarise(valor = mean(as.numeric(valor))) %>% 
  mutate(country = case_when(ocde == 1 ~ "OCDE", ocde != 1 ~ " ")) %>% select(-"ocde")

datalatam_qjp <- usaid_pry2 %>% filter(latam == 1) %>% 
  select(country, year, `Court structure and proceedings (0-5) (DB17-20 methodology)`, 
         `Case management (0-6) (DB17-20 methodology)`,
         `Court automation (0-4) (DB17-20 methodology)`,
         `Alternative dispute resolution (0-3) (DB17-20 methodology)`, latam) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(`Court structure and proceedings (0-5) (DB17-20 methodology)`)) %>% 
  gather(., 3:6, key = componentes, value = valor) %>% group_by(year, componentes, latam) %>% 
  summarise(valor = mean(as.numeric(valor))) %>% 
  mutate(country = case_when(latam == 1 ~ "Latinoamérica", latam != 1 ~ " ")) %>% select(-"latam")

datauppermid_qjp <- usaid_pry2 %>% filter(`upper-middle` == 1) %>% 
  select(country, year, `Court structure and proceedings (0-5) (DB17-20 methodology)`, 
         `Case management (0-6) (DB17-20 methodology)`,
         `Court automation (0-4) (DB17-20 methodology)`,
         `Alternative dispute resolution (0-3) (DB17-20 methodology)`, `upper-middle`) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(`Court structure and proceedings (0-5) (DB17-20 methodology)`)) %>% 
  gather(., 3:6, key = componentes, value = valor) %>% group_by(year, componentes, `upper-middle`) %>% 
  summarise(valor = mean(as.numeric(valor))) %>% 
  mutate(country = case_when(`upper-middle` == 1 ~ "Upper-middle income", `upper-middle` != 1 ~ " ")) %>% 
  select(-`upper-middle`)

dataqjp <- Reduce(function(...) merge (..., all=T), 
                  list(datapry_qjp, dataocde_qjp, datalatam_qjp, datauppermid_qjp))
dataqjp$valor <- as.numeric(dataqjp$valor)

ggplot(data = dataqjp) + aes(x = year, y = valor, fill = componentes) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + facet_grid(.~country) +
  labs(x = "años", y = "Ranking calidad del proceso judicial", 
       title = "Ranking calidad del proceso judicial por año", 
       caption = "Fuente: Doing Business (2020)") + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,18), expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme_minimal() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#FFCC99", "#CC99FF"), 
                    name = "Componentes", 
                    labels = c("Resolución alternativa de conflictos",
                               "Manejo de casos",
                               "Automatización de la corte",
                               "Estructura y procedimientos judiciales"))
```

De esta forma obtuve el gráfico deseado que es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Es una buena estrategia abrir las columnas en filas mediante `gather()`, la salida que obtienes es más "amigable" con ggplot. Tus datos tienen una estructura similar esta:

```
df <- data.frame(country = rep('paraguay',20),
                 year = rep(2016:2020,4),
                 componentes = rep(c('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'),5),
                 valor = runif(20)
                 )
df

    country year componentes      valor
1  Paraguay 2016          c1 0.58093243
2  Paraguay 2017          c2 0.06374806
3  Paraguay 2018          c3 0.39218578
4  Paraguay 2019          c4 0.69822312
5  Paraguay 2020          c1 0.78197417
6  Paraguay 2016          c2 0.30089809
7  Paraguay 2017          c3 0.17990927
8  Paraguay 2018          c4 0.34782483
9  Paraguay 2019          c1 0.32914443
10 Paraguay 2020          c2 0.62308575
11 Paraguay 2016          c3 0.34531712
12 Paraguay 2017          c4 0.32301550
13 Paraguay 2018          c1 0.52422446
14 Paraguay 2019          c2 0.58585572
15 Paraguay 2020          c3 0.06959481
16 Paraguay 2016          c4 0.32538488
17 Paraguay 2017          c1 0.07072949
18 Paraguay 2018          c2 0.64734311
19 Paraguay 2019          c3 0.95145716
20 Paraguay 2020          c4 0.20515947
```

Podemos hacer una gráfica de barras apiladas así:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x=year, y=valor, fill=componentes), position="stack")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La dimensión `fill` es la que establece el color de "llenado", la de `color` establece el color del borde, o de las lineas o curvas que eventualmente dibujes.

Si quieres barras paralelas, deberías usar `position="dodge"`:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x=year, y=valor, fill=componentes), position="dodge")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, tu ayuda fue muy útil!